# Alien in a box killed by humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There is a specific short story from an anthology type thing that I'm looking for from the 50s through the 80s (sorry it's such a wide range). The story is there were a bunch of people that found a box with something alien living inside. There was a coded message that no one could figure out. The people talk about the dangers of what the alien life form could bring and what they should do with it.

Eventually, they decide to kill the alien. The shoot it, and it oozes through the box. Someone that had been working on the code and had left then came back. Without noticing that the alien was dead, he proclaims that he cracked the code. He shouts that it said something like "Please take care of my daughter for me."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**There is a specific short story from an anthology type thing that I'm looking for from the 50s through the 80s (sorry it's such a wide range).**

["Doorstep"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57900) by [Keith Laumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Laumer), first published in [*Galaxy Magazine*, February 1961](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58501+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v19n03_1961-02#page/n31/mode/2up). You might have read it in a Laumer collection such as [*Nine by Laumer*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?195705) or [*The Best of Keith Laumer*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35821), or in the anthology [*Young Extraterrestrials*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?276716) aka [*Extraterrestrials*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178133) aka [*Asimov's Extraterrestrials*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178073). Is any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?57900) familiar?

**The story is there were a bunch of people that found a box**

> The general dropped the phone back on its cradle and absently peeled the cellophane from a cigar. He had moved fast, he reflected, after the State Police notified him at nine forty-one last night. He had his men on the spot, the area evacuated of civilians, and a preliminary report on its way to Washington by midnight. At two thirty-six, they had discovered the four-inch cube lying on the ground fifteen feet from the huge object—missile, capsule, bomb—whatever it was.

**with something alien living inside.**

> "What the devil's that racket?"
>
> "That's the sound we were getting from inside before, General. There's something in there, alive--"

**There was a coded message that no one could figure out.**

> "We'll review that matter at a later date. What I'm calling about is more important right now. The code men have made some headway on that box of yours. It's putting out a sort of transmission."
>
> "What kind, sir?"
>
> "Half the message—it's only twenty seconds long, repeated—is in English. It's a fragment of a recording from a daytime radio program; one of the network men here identified it. The rest is gibberish. They're still working on it."
>
> "What--"
>
> "Bryant tells me he thinks there may be some sort of correspondence between the two parts of the message. I wouldn't know, myself. In my opinion, it's a threat of some sort."

**The people talk about the dangers of what the alien life form could bring and what they should do with it. Eventually, they decide to kill the alien.**

> He looked at Major Greer. "I'm neutralizing this thing once and for all. There'll be no more men killed."
>
> Lieberman stood up. "General, I must protest any attack against this—"
>
> Straut whirled. "I'm handling this, Professor. I don't know who let you in here or why—but I'll make the decisions. I'm stopping this man-killer before it comes out of its nest, maybe gets into that village beyond the woods. There are four thousand civilians there. It's my job to protect them."

**The shoot it, and it oozes through the box.**

> The mortar fired with a muffled thud. Straut watched tensely. Five seconds later, the object erupted in a gout of pale pink debris. The lid rocked, pinkish fluid running down its opalescent surface. A second burst, a third. A great fragment of the menacing claw hung from the branch of a tree a hundred feet from the ship.

**Someone that had been working on the code and had left then came back. Without noticing that the alien was dead, he proclaims that he cracked the code.**

> The telephone rang. Straut picked it up.
>
> "General Straut," he said. His voice was firm. He had put an end to the threat.
>
> "Straut, we've broken the message," General Margrave said excitedly. "It's the damnedest thing I ever . . ."
>
> Straut wanted to interrupt, announce his victory, but Margrave was droning on.
>
> ". . . strange sort of reasoning, but there was a certain analogy. In any event, I'm assured the translation is accurate. Here's how it reads in English . . ."

**He shouts that it said something like "Please take care of my daughter for me."**

> Straut listened. Then he carefully placed the receiver back on the hook.
>
> Lieberman stared at him.
>
> "What did it say?"
>
> Straut cleared his throat. He turned and looked at Lieberman for a long moment before answering.
>
> "It said, 'Please take good care of my little girl.'"

Comment: +1 Good find. I'm a bit sad after reading your summary :(